# Set first row in an Ultragrid to always have the same value

Tags: c#, ultrawingrid

I have an ultragrid that displays items for a chosen category. There is always a default item of 'All' listed for each category, and I want this to appear as the first row in my ultragrid. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: How did u try so far? Add more details to your question.

Comment: Could you show the code that initialize your grid with the values to be displayed?

Comment: Are you allowing users to sort by any column?